# How to read Sharepoint folder from a standalone Windows application (C# based)

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint

I have a standalone Windows app written in C#, that needs to connect to a Sharepoint folder and list/read all the files in that directory. I have not been able to find a solution.

Some people suggest getting Microsoft.Sharepoint.DLL which lets you read files and folders easily, but when I try to install Sharepoint web services it tells me it can only be installed on Windows server. Is there any (and preferably simple) way to just connect to a Sharepoint folder and just get the contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Managed Client Object Model:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee857094(v=office.14).aspx

...or connect to the folder via SharePoint's web services:
http://sarangasl.blogspot.com/2009/12/sharepoint-list-web-service.html